# HTTP сервер работает в моей стране, но не работает в других

Tags: node.js, http

Я сделал HTTP сервер на nodejs, настроил переадресацию на роутере, и сайт нормально работает с других устройств и сетей ИЗ МОЕЙ СТРАНЫ. Но когда другие люди пробовали зайти на сайт из других  стран(Россия и Таджикистан, но скорее всего из других стран тоже не работает), то у них выдаёт таймаут подключения к сайту. IP адрес динамический. Что может решить проблему?

Comment: страна то какая, Казахстан?

Comment: @eri Узбекистан

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*не совсем ответ, но слишком много для коментария*

Для проверки доступности сайта из мира можно воспользоваться https://atlas.ripe.net/

Чтоб понять в каком теряется нужно выполнить трассировку c двух сторон. Если обычная не покажет виновника, то сделать через `tracetcp.exe`, `tcptraceroute`, `traceroute -T`.

Какой IP адрес у Вашего сервера? Точнее у роутера - отображается в состоянии подключения. Адреса на 192.168.0/24, 172.16.0/12, 10.0/8, 100.0/8 могут работать внутри одного провайдера.

Пробовали ли подключаться через IPv6 (если он есть)?

Трассировка из билайн-россия обрывается на адресе

```
 3:  213.234.199.107                                      10.011ms 
 4:  10.2.246.210                                          1.913ms 
 5:  195.218.139.25                                        2.503ms 
 6:  79.104.225.59                                         8.334ms asymm 10 
 7:  77.41.170.150                                         8.128ms asymm 10 
 8:  5.187.73.94                                          20.084ms asymm 10 
 9:  178.210.33.165                                       60.452ms asymm 12 
10:  195.69.189.46                                        59.750ms 
11:  195.69.189.32                                        59.898ms asymm 10 
12:  195.69.189.235                                       60.102ms asymm 10 
13:  81.95.234.9                                          95.415ms asymm 11
```

Адрес '81.95.234.0/24 AS12365' принадлежит   Sarkor-Telecom Company,  7 Shakhrisabzskaya str., Tashkent, Uzbekistan, phone:+99878 1220000 . Блокировка происходит на стороне провайдера. Вызвана она может несколькими причинами: ограничение тарифа, антивирусом на стороне провайдера (у моего провайдера есть такая, можно отключить в личном кабинете или по заявке) или законом о связи Вашей страны.

Позвоните Вашему провайдеру.

Comment: IPv6 есть, но не пробовал. Сам сервер запущен на 192.168.0.100(локальный адрес ноута, на котором сервер), а роутер с внешнего запроса перенаправляет на ноут.  Есть такой вариант, что в мире есть другое устройство с таким-же внешним IP адресом как у меня, и люди и из других стран подключаются именно к нему?

Comment: Внешний IP - 89.146.120.204. Сервер сейчас запущен

Comment: @NekitKuzmenko, обновил ответ

Comment: Верно, оказывается саркор блокировал 25, 80 и 443 порт. На других портах всё исправно работает. Спасибо